# How do I open links in one browser automatically in another?

Tags: 12.04, browser, midori

I'd like links I click on in Midori to automatically open in another web browser, Firefox.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you'd have to modify Midori in order to do that. Perhaps you could make an addon. One way might be to add an option in a right-click menu, for instance. There is no general way of doing something like that, that I know of.